# show each value from arraylist to each textView Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, textview

I'm trying to show each value in my arraylist to each textView which I created manually or fixed textView

```
    totalCardPerPage = 30;
    cardNumber = 1;
    //looping to determine textView id in my xml
    for(int x=1;x<=totalCardPerPage;x++){
        //textView id
        textId = "text"+cardNumber;
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(textId, "id", "com.example.radioexample");
        TextView currcell = (TextView) findViewById(id);
        //get array size
        int arrayListSize = arrayListPage1.size();

        //looping to show each value in textView
        for(int y=0; y<=arrayListSize; y++){
            currcell.setText(arrayListPage1.get(y).toString);
            currcell.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        cardNumber++;
    }
```

the problem is the looping to show each value in textView.

I got an error when run this code

I realized it for the looping in arraylist, all the value from my array get together in one textView only

it should be if there is 5 value in my array, each value will be shown in each textView.

For example,

```
 arraylist {a,b,c,d,e};
 text1.setText(a);
 text2.setText(b);
 text3.setText(c);
 text4.setText(d);
 text5.setText(e);
```

anyone know how to do it?

thanks

Comment: Dynamically create and add the textviews to a parent layout.

Comment: @jitainsharma in this case, I need to create it manually or fixed textView

Comment: What you can do is, create a layout with textview only, inflate this layout in each for loop and add it to the main layout parent view.

Answer (score -1):

This question is old `BUT` is the first result in Google search .

For do this work you must call all values of **arraylist** in a loop and set on special **Textview** like this code :

if you have this arraylist and textviews

```
arraylist {a,b,c,d,e};

 TextView []tv=new TextView[5];
tv[0]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
tv[1]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
tv[2]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
tv[3]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
tv[4]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
```

// loop for load arraylist into special Textviews

```
 for(int i=0;i<arraylist.size();i++)
                {
                   tv[i].setText(arraylist.get(i).toString());
                }
```